# Codeblocks installation

Tags: dependencies

I have tried to install codeblocks following the instructions on:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_Code::Blocks_nightly_build_on_Ubuntu

but finally did something wrong.

```
woelrat@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep codeb
ii  codeblocks 13.12-3 amd64        Code::Blocks integrated development environment (IDE)
ii  codeblocks-common                                     13.12-3                                             all          common files for Code::Blocks IDE
iU  codeblocks-contrib-dbg                                13.12-3                                             amd64        dummy transitional package for Code::Blocks debugging symbols
iU  codeblocks-dbg                                        13.12-3                                             amd64        Code::Blocks debugging libraries
ii  codeblocks-dev                                        13.12-1                                             amd64        Code::Blocks development libraries (SDK)
ri  codeblocks-headers                                    13.12-1                                             all          Code::Blocks development headers (SDK)
ri  codeblocks-libwxcontrib0                              13.12-1                                             amd64        Code::Blocks shared libraries for wxContribItems
ri  codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev                              13.12-1                                             amd64        Code::Blocks development libraries for wxContribItems
ii  codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers                          13.12-1                                             all          Code::Blocks development headers for wxContribItems
ii  libcodeblocks0                                        13.12-1                                             amd64        Code::Blocks shared libraries
```

I already tried `sudo apt-get -f install` with following errors:

```
Preparing to unpack .../codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking codeblocks-dev (13.12-3) over (13.12-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/codeblocks/externaldepsdlg.h', which is also in package codeblocks-headers 13.12-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

codeblocks-dbg : Depends: codeblocks-contrib (= 13.12-3) but it is not going to be installed

codeblocks-headers : Depends: codeblocks-dev (>= 13.12-1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: codeblocks-dev (< 13.12-1.1~) but it is not going to be installed

libwxsmithlib0 : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 13.12-3) but 13.12-1 is to be installed
              Recommends: codeblocks-contrib (= 13.12-3) but it is not going to be installed
libwxsmithlib0-dev : Depends: libwxsmithlib-dev (= 13.12-3) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Some tips how I can solve this? Where do I need to start?

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwxsmithlib0 libwxsmithlib0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libwxsmithlib0 is already the newest version.
libwxsmithlib0-dev is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-dbg : Depends: codeblocks-contrib (= 13.12-3) but it is not going to be installed
 libwxsmithlib0 : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 13.12-3) but 13.12-1 is to be installed
                  Recommends: codeblocks-contrib (= 13.12-3) but it is not going to be installed
 libwxsmithlib0-dev : Depends: libwxsmithlib-dev (= 13.12-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I still have a problem with dependencies. Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: If you want to install the wxsmith and/or contrib packages, you must install the libwxsmithlib0 package first. 
`apt-get install libwxsmithlib0 libwxsmithlib0-dev` . Make sure you have your universe and multiverse repositories enabled.

Comment: I tried apt-get install libwxsmithlib0 libwxsmithlib0-dev but I still have a problem with dependencies (see original post). Someone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the packages individually. (you need to find out the right order!)

```
sudo dpkg -i packages-name.deb
```

needed to force the remove of one of the packages (Dependencies were in a loop between tree packages)

Installed codeblocks with the ubuntu software manager. This was done in 5 minutes :-)

Answer (score 0):

@woelrat thanks for your reply. I have just solved my same problem.

Steps:

- List all relative packets about codeblocks

  ```
  dpkg --list | grep -i codeblocks
  ```
- Then remove packages have unmet dependencies

  ```
  sudo dpkg --purge codeblocks-dev
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get -f install
  ```

Voilaaa..

Maybe your software-center is crashed by some failures. I suggest you fresh install

```
sudo apt-get remove -f software-center && sudo apt-get install -f software-center
```

Now you can install stable version of codeblocks using software-center.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt purge codeblocks*
```

This will remove all file related to codeblocks.
Then try:

```
sudo apt -f install

sudo apt autoremove
```

Your issue will be solved
and install it from Ubuntu software for easy installation.