# Code blocks not loading "The following packages have unmet dependencies "

Tags: code-blocks, held-packages

[Codeblocks installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688385/codeblocks-installation) 
I tried this but it didn't work. I'm new on Ubuntu, can you help?

Comment: You refer to a five-year old question. Your system is probably different from theirs. Installing `codeblocks` should start with `sudo apt install codeblocks`. What is your exact error?

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 codeblocks : Depends: codeblocks-common (= 17.12-0ubuntu2~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try to manually install `codeblocks-common` : `sudo apt install codeblocks-common` and see why it won't be installed. I suspect you need to remove some obsolete packages before you can cleanly install `codeblocks`.

Comment: fatma@fatma-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X509FB-X509FB:~$ sudo apt install codeblocks-common
[sudo] password for fatma: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
codeblocks-common is already the newest version (17.12-1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

Comment: Try `sudo apt remove codeblocks-common` followed by `sudo apt install codeblocks`.

Comment: It was dissolved! Thanks :)